# How do you throw your drone without going on cams?

Tags: ps4, rainbow-six-siege

I see a lot of people throw there drone in and then move to a safer place to use it but whenever I throw my drone I'm forced onto cams no matter what I do. What do I press to just throw my drone and not use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should go into Settings and search for Advanced Drone Deployment option. [Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Rainbow6/comments/8y64wq/advanced_drone_deployment_allows_you_to_toss/)